# Jenkins pipeline: Should I clean workspace before unstash workspace on new node?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to switch build node and transfer whole workspace to a new node.

```
node('node1') {
    ...
    stash 'my_workspace'
}

node('node2') {
    ...
    unstash 'my_workspace'
}
```

What will `unstash` command do with old files in workspace on `node2`? Should I cleanup workspace on `node2` before unstash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What will unstash command do with old files in workspace on node2?

They will still be in workspace.

> Should I cleanup workspace on node2 before unstash?

I don't know your use case. If you would like to clean up workspace on node2, call `deleteDir()` before `unstash`.